# React Native with React Native Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

Does anyone know how to use @react-Native-firebase/auth with react native v 0.62.0? I am having a tough time setting up user authentication and I am fairly new at coding. Any recommendations would be helpful!

Comment: Did you follow [Integrate Into Existing Project](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/quick-start/existing-project) and [Auth Quick Start](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/auth/quick-start)?

Comment: Yes I did. My struggle is getting the code to function and the placement of it.

Comment: What does your code look like so far? And what error message do you see / how do you know it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [@react-Native-firebase/auth](https://rnfirebase.io/auth) is pretty good.

The [introduction](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage#installation) section instructs you that the "auth" module requires that the @react-native-firebase/app module is already setup and installed. To install the "app" module, view the [Getting Started](https://rnfirebase.io/) documentation.

If you have any trouble in this part, please provide a more detailed report.